# Freemarker: Dynamic interpolation of sub variables

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to create a FreeMarker macro that can return the interpolation of a concatenation of a string and the input variable:

```
<#macro findValue var>
   <#if (.vars["foo." + var]) ??> 
     .vars["foo." + var]
   <#else>
     ${.vars["bar." + var]}
   </#if>
</#macro>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Firstly, `${.vars["bar." + var]}` gives an `undefined` error. Secondly, the `if` condition always returns `false` even when I can see that the sub variable do exist. It seems like the `.vars` variable can only look up root variables, but not sub variables like `foo.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FreeMarker, `foo.bar` is the same as `foo["bar"]`, but inside the `[]` you can have an arbitrary expression that *evaluates* to a string. So the expression you are looking for is simply `foo[var]`.

BTW, what your macro tries to do is just `${foo[var]!bar[var]}`

Comment: Sorry. I hope it is fixed now.