# Access template model from a macro using parameter

Tags: freemarker

I have a form with input field (the example is simplified):

```
<input type="text" value="${model.person.age}">
```

This is working as expected and now I want to write a macro for this:

```
 <#macro input path inputType="text">
    <input type="${inputType}" value="${model[path]}">
</#macro>
```

that can be used with

```
 <@lib.input "person.age" />
```

I found ${model[path]} solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392822/freemarker-dynamic-interpolation-of-sub-variables) but it does not work in my case. I'm using Freemarker 2.3.21 and Spring MVC 4.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just pass in the value itself, like  `<@lib.input person.age>`? Anyway, if you absolutely have to pass in that expression unevaluated, then in the macro you can use `value="${path?eval}"`. It need not be a "path" of course, it can be any kind of expression. (`model[path]` doesn't work, since the value inside the `[]` meant to be a variable name, which can contain any characters, not some kind of path expression.)

Comment: **It works, thanks a lot**. Passing the value itself is not an option because I need the path for other values (e.g. input name, label text). If I understood well, only variables can be used in _[]_. Can I create a variable with _path_ expression value? The code bellow does not work and I suppose I'm missing something again. `<#macro input path inputType="text">  <#local pathVar=path>  <input type="${inputType}" value="${model[pathVar]}">  </#macro>`

Comment: `[]` contains an arbitrary complex expression that's evaluated as usual, and the resulting value (which must be a string) will be used as the subvariable name. `foo.bar` is the same as `foo['bar']`, only with `[]` the subvariable name can be dynamic (like `foo["b" + rest]`) and it can contain any characters.

Comment: What would be the exact syntax of a "path" BTW?

Comment: The exact syntax is given in the original question - it is "person.age".

Comment: That's just an example, but whatever. Anything that wasn't solved with `?eval`?